# How to register the enter key using readline() in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am currently using readline() function in Kotlin. However, I want it to continue after registering the enter key ten times. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the function `readline()` on a console application that is reading from the keyboard, you dont need to register the enter-key because ENTER represents a valid end of the line. So a simple loop which is executed 10 times will fully work out here. `for(i in 0..9) { <READ INPUT> }`

Using it on files works the same. Normal editors will show a text in X lines if the border window is reached even without ENTER. `readline()` will not do that and read a single line in a file until a line-end sign is found. So here again - just loop it 10 times for 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not very clear, what you are trying to achieve. I assume you want to read ten lines from the console with `Console.readLine()`.

The code

```
val lines = (1..10).map { readLine() }
```

will read ten lines from the console and store them in the variable `lines` as list of strings.